# Getting array key(from column 2) and array value(from column 1) from database

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have an array that looks like this

```
$casearrayF = array(
        '0' => 'a',
        '0' => 'b', 
        '15' => 'c');
```

I want to create a **similar** array by fetching data from database and the data table looks like this

```
letter | value | 
a      | 0     |
b      | 0     |
c      | 15    |
       | 0     |
```

My current php code is

```
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "test";
$conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username,  $password,  $db);
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM alphabet WHERE letter <> ''";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array[$row['value']] = $row['letter'];
}
```

The issue I'm facing right now is when try to `echo key($array)` the values are all 0's instead of 0,0,15. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Array with same keys cannot __exist__.

Comment: use `array_flip`

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. As pointed out arrays can't have duplicate keys. Also `key()` probably doesn't do what you think it does, why do you use it?

Comment: I'm trying to do a `<select><option>` dropdown list with the `<option value = $row'letter'>` and compare the selected option value to the array value and to get the specific key which is the value allocated for the letter @Dharman
is there any way for me to do that since key cant have the same value?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want your array to look like this:

```
[['a',0],['b',0],['c',15]]
```

then you would have:

```
array_push($array,[$row['letter'], $row['value']]);
```